# Database path in main isolate and other isolate

Tags: flutter, drift, isolate

I am writing database from background thread for this I have used isolate.But after writing data unable to get updated data from main thread to update UI.
I have checked it like right after inserting data I am getting count of inserted entries its give me right count. and write after this whole operation I am getting count from main thread but here the count is 0. Even I am building app again means not using hot reload.

I have registered my database like this in main thread:

```
LazyDatabase openConnection({bool logStatements = false}) {
  return LazyDatabase(() async {
    final dbFolder = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File(p.join(dbFolder.path, 'myDatabase.sqlite'));
    return NativeDatabase(file,logStatements: logStatements);
  });
}
```

and in isolate accessing it like

```
 Future<DatabaseConnection> _backgroundConnection() async {
   final dbFolder = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();// here getting error
    final file = File(p.join(dbFolder.path, 'myDatabase.sqlite'));
    final database =NativeDatabase(file, logStatements: true);
    return DatabaseConnection.fromExecutor(database);
  }
```

Comment: You don't have the same db name: `myatabase.sqlite` vs `myDatabase.sqlite`

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? Having a similar issue where the .watch() stream on main thread doesn't update if I write to the database from a background task.

Comment: Same here, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NativeDatabase.createBackgroundConnection`.